# PyModbus failing to RTU Over TCP Due to adding TCP header

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I am using Serial Ethernet Device Server  (CSE-H55N2)
https://www.eztcp.com/en/download/pds_files/an_ezmanager_en.pdf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGhCZ.png)

When using the MAC address notification function of CSE-H55N2, the MAC address is added to the Modbus signal and transmitted through TCP communication.

When using the MAC address notification function, the following error occurs in pymodbus.

There is no error if the MAC address notification function of CSE-H55N2 is not used.

How can I receive data without error while using the MAC address notification function?

It seems that a CRC error occurs when the data in the TCP header part occurs. How should I solve it?

The program source code is as follows

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer as ModbusFramer


import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

ip = "x.x.x.x" 
port_num = x
unit_num = 1


client = ModbusTcpClient(ip, port=port_num, framer=ModbusFramer)
client.connect()
rr = client.read_input_registers(0,10, unit=unit_num)  
print(rr,rr.registers)
```

and the result is this:

```
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Current transaction state - IDLE
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Running transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:SEND: 0x18 0x4 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xa 0x72 0x4
DEBUG:pymodbus.client.sync:New Transaction state 'SENDING'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:RECV: 0x30 0x30 0x33 0x30 0x66 0x39 0x31 0x31 0x34 0x30 0x38 0x35 0xd 0xa 0x18 0x4 0x14 0x55 0xb 0x2 0x52 0xac 0x9 0x1 0x28
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:CRC invalid, discarding header!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer - 0x30 0x30 0x33 0x30 0x66 0x39 0x31 0x31 0x34 0x30 0x38 0x35 0xd 0xa 0x18 0x4 0x14 0x55 0xb 0x2 0x52 0xac 0x9 0x1 0x28
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame check failed, ignoring!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer -
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Getting transaction 24
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\devel\python\pymodbus\namjun_mac2.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(rr,rr.registers)
AttributeError: 'ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'registers'
```

Important part

```
good result
SEND: 0x1 0x4 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xa 0x70 0xd
RECV: 0x1 0x4 0x14 0x9b 0xf7 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x22 0x0 0x0 0x79 0xef 0x43 0xba 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xa7 0xae 0x43 0xbb 0x39 0x10

error result : added TCP header (MAC address)
SEND: 0x18 0x4 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xa 0x72 0x4
RECV: 0x30 0x30 0x33 0x30 0x66 0x39 0x31 0x31 0x34 0x30 0x38 0x35 0xd 0xa 0x18 0x4 0x14 0x6c 0x4 0x2 0x49 0x8b 0x19 0x1 0x24
```